# I can't update content from CKEditor to sql server (use asp.net web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ckeditor

I use asp.net web form to make a website.
Then I install CKEditor and can insert content into sql server.
However I'd like to use CKEditor to update data in database is failed.
This is my aspx code

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AboutUsContent.aspx.cs" Inherits="yacht.admin.AboutUsContent" %>
<%@ Register assembly="CKEditor.NET" namespace="CKEditor.NET" tagprefix="CKEditor" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <!-- [ Main Content ] start -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <h5>Update About Us Content</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl2" runat="server" BasePath="/Scripts/ckeditor/" Toolbar="Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|Subscript|Superscript|-|RemoveFormat
        NumberedList|BulletedList|-|Outdent|Indent|-|JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock|-|BidiLtr|BidiRtl
        /
        Styles|Format|Font|FontSize
        TextColor|BGColor
        Link|Image">
                                            </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
                                       </div>
                                        <br/>
                                       <div style="margin:auto;">
                                            <asp:Button ID="SubmitBTN" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitBTN_Click" class="btn  btn-secondary btn-sm" />
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <!-- [ Main Content ] end -->
</asp:Content>
```

This is my aspx.cs code

```
namespace yacht.admin
{
    public partial class AboutUsContent : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string getsql = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yachtConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileBrowser fileBrowser = new FileBrowser();
            fileBrowser.BasePath = "/ckfinder";
            fileBrowser.SetupCKEditor(CKEditorControl2);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(getsql);
            string sql = "SELECT AboutUsContent FROM AboutUs WHERE id = 1";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                CKEditorControl2.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(reader["AboutUsContent"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        protected void SubmitBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string aboutUs = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(CKEditorControl2.Text);
            DateTime getdate = DateTime.Now;
            string dateNow = getdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(getsql);
            string sql = "UPDATE AboutUs SET AboutUsContent = @AboutUsContent, LastMotifiedDate = @LastMotifiedDate WHERE id = 1";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AboutUsContent", aboutUs);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastMotifiedDate", dateNow);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            Response.Redirect("AboutUs");
        }
    }
}
```

When I edited content in CKEditor, it couldn't update to sql server
(It can't grab CKEditor's content)
I tried it for whole day, what can I do now....
Thanks first for all of you.

Comment: `It can't grab CKEditor's content` what does it mean? How do you confirm this? Did you debug your code? what value you have in `aboutUs`? Can you share the code of `INSERT` operation too?

Comment: Try writing the code of `Page_Load` inside `if(!IsPostBack)` block.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I can update data into database now！I didn't write if(!IsPostBack), that's the reason why I failed before. Thank you so so so much! "It can't grab CKEditor's content" means when I debug, I found that it can't find content and save. Thank you again.